# How do I get a tensor of an specific value and shape in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I want to make a tensor of 0.9 of an specific shape. In tensorflow there is this command:

tf.ones_like()

So I put there the shape and I have my vector of ones. I want to do the same but with other value like 0.9, so I want to put the shape like in tf.ones_like but I want my tensor with this number 0.9

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use fill

```
# Output tensor has shape [2, 3].
fill([2, 3], 0.9) ==> [[0.9, 0.9, 0.9]
                 [0.9, 0.9, 0.9]]
```